# Function is returned before value assigned to it. How to avoid this?

Tags: angular, function, return, angular-services

I want to use returned Boolean flag in IF condition in 1st function as shown below, however, 2nd function is returned before the actual value is assigned through a service. Help is really appreciated.

```
subModuleLoggedInCheck(component: string): boolean {
   console.log(this.retrieveSubModuleLoggedInInfo(component)); // always return false which is invalid
   if (!this.retrieveSubModuleLoggedInInfo(component)) {
     return this.createUpdateLoggedInRecord(component, 1);
   } else {
     this.openGenericDialog('GenericAlert', "Some text...");
     this.dialogRef.afterClosed()
      .subscribe(result => {

     });
   return false;
  }
}

retrieveSubModuleLoggedInInfo(component: string): boolean {
  var flag = false;
  this.activeUserService.getSubModuleLoggedInInfo('Retrieve', 'AccountsPayable', component)
     .subscribe((data) => {
        if(data) {
          flag= true;
          // console.log(flag);
        } else {
          flag= false;
        }
     });
     return flag;
 }
```

Error on working out below given solution:

1. updated code and tried removing Boolean return type 
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD0jS.png)
2. updated code and tried retained Boolean return type 
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkBMc.png)

Answer (score 1):

So here you need to set return your `flag`'s value inside the `subscribe()` block.
This is because it is an `async` type and the code below will get executed even if the `subscribe()` block is still under execution.

So you need to update your 2nd function `retrieveSubModuleLoggedInInfo()` as:

```
retrieveSubModuleLoggedInInfo(component: string): boolean {
 let flag = false;
  this.activeUserService.getSubModuleLoggedInInfo('Retrieve', 'AccountsPayable', component)
     .subscribe((data: any) => {
        if(data) {
          flag = true;
          return flag;
        } else {
          flag = false;
          return flag;
        }
     });
 }
```

**OR**

You can also shorten your `subscribe()` block code and your skip the `flag` variable creation as:

```
retrieveSubModuleLoggedInInfo(component: string): boolean {
  this.activeUserService.getSubModuleLoggedInInfo('Retrieve', 'AccountsPayable', component)
     .subscribe((data: any) => {
        return !!data;
     });
 }
```

Comment: with above code.. I'm getting an error function with return type boolean should return a value and "boolean " underlined in red.

Comment: @KuntadyYathish Which one is throwing an error? 1st or 2nd? Can you try adding `(data: any)` in the subscribe argument? and also can you try removing `: boolean` return type from function?

Comment: Error is in 2nd function(line #1 2nd function)  and I can't remove it as it's required for IF condition check ( ref line #3 of my post )

Comment: @KuntadyYathish I'm justing asking to remove the return notation. But let the return statement be `return !!data;`.
Also, have you tried adding `:any` to the argument of subscription block?

Comment: I tried your approach but no luck.. I updated my post with code screenshots to spotlight the line, please check. Hope I'm conveying current issue correctly

Comment: @KuntadyYathish Have you tried using the 1st approach which have the `if` block? If it still doesn't work. Can you re-generate this issue here https://StackBlitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

Kundaty, in general, if in a function you has an observable and you want return a value, the better aproach is return an observable, so you don't call the function else subscribe to this. For this you use "switchMap", that allow us use the response and "of" to return an observable of any variable. Imagine your function like

```
import {of,Observable} from 'rxjs'
import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators'

retrieveSubModuleLoggedInInfo(component: string): Observable<boolean>
{ 
  return this.activeUserService.getSubModuleLoggedInInfo('Retrieve', 'AccountsPayable', component)
    .pipe(switchMap(data=>{
    //here you has the value of "data"
        if(data) {
          flag= true;
          // console.log(flag);
        } else {
          flag= false;
        }
        //you need return an observable, use the 'rxjs' of
        return of(flag)
   }))
}
```

See that your function not return a boolean else an Observable. See how, we don't subscribe in the function, else using a switchMap we change the response, we not return data else of(flag)

Then you "call" to the function subscribing

```
this.retrieveSubModuleLoggedInInfo("hello").subscribe(res=>{
   //res will be true or false
})
```

I know that is complex but, if you get used to use Observables, early love it

**Update** well, our function retrieveSubModuleLoggedInInfo return a Observable, So, we change our function

```
retrieveSubModuleLoggedInCheck(component: string): boolean {
   this.retrieveSubModuleLoggedInInfo(component).subscribe(res=>{
      if (!res)
        return this.createUpdateLoggedInRecord(component, 1);

      this.openGenericDialog('GenericAlert', "Some text...");
      this.dialogRef.afterClosed()
        .subscribe(result => {

     });
  })
}
```

Well, what happens if we can call to a function that return an observable in a loop. Well, forkjoin comes to rescue, imagine you has an array of strings

```
//we create an array of observables
//we can use the map javascript method
const obs:Observables<any>[]=myArray.map(x=>this.retrieveSubModuleLoggedInInfo(x)) forkjoin(obs).subscribe((res:any[])=>{
    //in res[0] we has the response of the first observables
    //in res[1] we has the response of the second observable
    ...
})
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure ,how to use this function for IF loop check condition.. in fact I'm stuck here ( ref line #3 of my post )

Comment: You function If you has a loop, again 'rxjs', (in this case `forkjoin` ) can help you. (I can't see the loop, I try sketch out in the update of the response